# How to dynamically add active class to li element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have multiple user role based system. Every user have many pages so in order to lessen the code i have used a header.php file with header as it is common to every page. I want to know how i can apply active tag to that element whose page is open with javascript. I have attached the code it is echoed using php, it is inside php echo tag. For example if i open home then class='active' should be added to the li of home.

```
if($role=='S')
{
 echo"<div class='navbar navbar-default' id='navbar-second'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav no-border visible-xs-block'>
    <li><a class='text-center collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbar-second-toggle'><i class='icon-menu7'></i></a></li>
</ul>

<div class='navbar-collapse collapse' id='navbar-second-toggle'>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li><a href='home'><i class='icon-home position-left'></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='examresult'><i class='icon-clipboard position-left'></i> Exam Result</a></li>
        <li><a href='attendance'><i class='icon-checkbox-checked2 position-left'></i> Attendance</a></li>
        <li><a href='timetable'><i class='icon-table2 position-left'></i> Time Table</a>
        <li><a href='assignment'><i class='icon-stack3 position-left'></i> Assignment</a></li>
        <li><a href='documents'><i class='icon-files-empty position-left'></i> Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href='feedback'><i class='icon-pencil4 position-left'></i> Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href='profile'><i class='icon-user position-left'></i> My Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li>
            <a href='developers' style='font-size:15px;'><i class='icon-hammer-wrench position-left'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Developers</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </div> 
  ";}
```

I have tried this javascript code but it is not working:-

```
 var selector = '.nav navbar-nav li';

 $(selector).on('click', function(){
 $(selector).removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
 });
```

Comment: try using this `$(selector).addClass('active')`

Comment: @FrayneKonok I have posted the javascript code that i have tried with ,addClass but it's not working.

Comment: What happens when you click on the link? Full page reload? If yes, then you need to do it with php, not js.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes full page reload. Can you please tell how to do it using php.

Comment: The problem is with `<a href='examresult'>`

Comment: @KushalSrivastava, So give your PHP Code so that we can help you.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Updated it with php code.

Comment: Why you use a `link` without extension? `<a href='examresult'>`

Comment: @FrayneKonok because i have rewrite engine on. I am using pretty url.

Comment: @KushalSrivastava, If your re-write engine on then configure it as your engine set. But this is the way you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your re-write engine on then configure it as your engine set. But this is
>   the way you can do this.

**PHP:**

Let you click on a link, so you get

```
$option = $_GET['option'];
$$option = "class='active'";
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
  <li <?php echo @$home;?>><a href='index.php?option=home'><i class='icon-home position-left'></i> Home</a></li>
  <li <?php echo @$examresult;?>><a href='index.php?option=examresult'><i class='icon-clipboard position-left'></i> Exam Result</a></li>
  <li <?php echo @$attendance;?>><a href='index.php?option=attendance'><i class='icon-checkbox-checked2 position-left'></i> Attendance</a></li>
  <li <?php echo @$timetable;?>><a href='index.php?option=timetable'><i class='icon-table2 position-left'></i> Time Table</a>
  <li <?php echo @$assignment;?>><a href='index.php?option=assignment'><i class='icon-stack3 position-left'></i> Assignment</a></li>
  <li <?php echo @$documents;?>><a href='index.php?option=documents'><i class='icon-files-empty position-left'></i> Documents</a></li>
  <li <?php echo @$feedback;?>><a href='index.php?option=feedback'><i class='icon-pencil4 position-left'></i> Feedback</a></li>
  <li <?php echo @$profile;?>><a href='index.php?option=profile'><i class='icon-user position-left'></i> My Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but  it's not working. The above navbar code is echoed through php. It is inside echo tag will that be a problem.

Comment: no that will be not a problem, you have use your code in a arranged way.

Comment: echo is not a tag at all. and why you do this? HTML is separate from the PHP. Don't mixed up them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#navbar-second-toggle')
  .find('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]')
  .parent('li')
  .addClass('active')
```

Comment: It's not working. The above navbar code is echoed through php. It is inside echo tag will that be a problem.

Comment: The DOM will convert href to an absolute URL. Will jQuery try to match that absolute URL or the relative path?  Regardless, up voting as this is a good approach.